# Is it possible to shutdown a Raspberry Pi with Windows 10 IoT from a UWP App

Tags: uwp, raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core

I want shutdown a Raspberry Pi with Windows 10 IoT from a UWP App from c# Code. Is this possible, because the UWP runs in the sandbox from Windows 10 IoT?

Comment: Note that a Pi cannot normally be switched off. It will shut down the OS, but not switch itself off, because it doesn't have the hardware to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a iot device to test, but you can refer to this post, https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2016/12/13/how-to-shutdown-a-windows-10-iot-core-device-from-a-uwp-app/